# Best Python UI Framework for simple display (no direct interaction)

Tags: python, user-interface, view, frameworks, display

*TL;DR*
How to create a simple "UI" to display a few pictures ("live feed") and update a few sliders to show the state of the application. Basically, how to tell the UI: "show this new image instead of the current one" and "highlight this unclickable button to show it is activated".

---

I have absolutely zero experience with user interface and graphical display, so I don't know what to google for this question. I have some python code that uses the raspberry pi camera to take pictures, process them a bit (filters) and that's it. I also have a few hardware components (buttons, joystick) to control that camera and the processing applied to the pictures, like filter selection and filter intensity. The hardware events are already handled through a main loop that polls the buttons/joystick controller. The loop also captures the pictures and processes them. Basically, the application is done.

Now, what would be the best way to simply display this information ? What is the best Python framework to achieve this ?

Would PyQT or Kivy allow me to do this ? I would want to show the "live feed", some button information (which button has been pressed to show what processing is currently done on the pictures) in a simple cute layout. There does not need to be anything clickable on the interface, as the interaction occurs on the hardware.

Thanks !

Comment: Asking for library recommendations are off-topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like the Tkinter library for these simpler tasks. It is quite similar to java Swing should you be familiar with that. Here is a sample code that does pretty much all you need, even though it is quite messy. It should help you out though.

[image: frame]

Note that Tkinter is very raw and not recommended for more elaborate needs.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time

#manipulating canvas items attributes
def change_color(canvas):
    if canvas.itemcget(label, 'fill') == 'black':
        canvas.itemconfig(label, fill='green')
    else:
        canvas.itemconfig(label, fill='black')

#changing image displayed
def change_image(canvas, current):
    if current == 1:
        canvas.itemconfig(img, image=photo2)
        return 2
    else:
        canvas.itemconfig(img, image=photo1)
        return 1

#slider gauge
def set_gauge(canvas, percentage):
    coords = canvas.coords(gaugefg)
    new_y = -2*percentage + 400
    coords[1] = new_y
    canvas.coords(gaugefg,coords)

color = 'black'
gauge = 0
delta = 10
root = tk.Tk()
#frame size and background
root.geometry('600x600')
root.configure(bg='white')
#make frame pop upfront
root.attributes("-topmost", True)

#uploading images from the same folder
photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('download.jpeg'))
photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('download1.jpeg'))
current_photo = 1

#canvas on with we'll be drawing
canvas = tk.Canvas(master=root, width=600, height=600)
#text label (xcenter,ycenter)
label = canvas.create_text(500, 500, text='Cool', fill=color, font=('purisa', 20))
#img component (xcenter, ycenter)
img = canvas.create_image(300, 300, image=photo1)
#gauge/slider = two superposed rectangles
#NOTE: (xtopleft, ytopleft, xbottomright, ybottomright)
gaugebg = canvas.create_rectangle(510, 200, 540, 400, fill='black')
gaugefg = canvas.create_rectangle(510, 300, 540, 400, fill='blue')
canvas.pack()

#Main Loop
while True:
    change_color(canvas)
    current_photo = change_image(canvas, current_photo)
    gauge += delta
    if gauge == 100 or gauge == 0:
        delta = -delta
    set_gauge(canvas, gauge)
    #update frame and canvas
    root.update()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I hope that helps you accomplish what you need. Any questions just text.

Comment: I ended up using PySimplyGUI that is basically a wrapper for tkinter. It is easy to use and lets me easily control the main loop.